# Finding who initiated command from a log?

Tags: linux, logging

I saw in log that someone initiated shutdown of our Odoo server. But that was not me and no one else has access to do it except our linux server provider, but it would be strange if they would shutdown Odoo for no reason. Can I somehow pin point the source who initiated the command?

```
2015-04-08 09:32:34,916 5156 INFO ? openerp.service.server: Initiating shutdown

2015-04-08 09:32:34,916 5156 INFO ? openerp.service.server: Hit CTRL-C again or send a second signal to force the shutdown.
```

Answer (score 2):

In short NO. From this log you only can retrieve the info that the log shows (obviously).

But if you have root access to the server (i can supose this), you can do some search to try to find the user. All depends on your system configuration.

For example you can check auth log (if shutdown was launched with sudo you will find the command and the user here). With the log's date you can filter against the access in auth log.